# Naming a Dynamic ProDataSet : Openedge

Tags: openedge

I want to assign a name(in the calling Procedure) to the ProDataSet created dynamically.

example:

```
RUN DynamicDataSet2.p 
  (INPUT "Order,OrderLine,Item",
   INPUT "OrderNum,LineNum,ItemNum",
   INPUT "OrderNum,OrderNum",
   INPUT "< 10",
   OUTPUT DATASET-HANDLE hDataSet)
```

Can the ProDataSet returned as an output parameter(handle) be assigned a name in the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`NAME` attribute](https://docs.progress.com/fr-FR/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/NAME-attribute.html) of a ProDataSet object handle is writeable so you can do :

```swift
RUN DynamicDataSet2.p 
  (INPUT "Order,OrderLine,Item",
   INPUT "OrderNum,LineNum,ItemNum",
   INPUT "OrderNum,OrderNum",
   INPUT "< 10",
   OUTPUT DATASET-HANDLE hDataSet).

hDataSet:NAME = "SomeName".
```